# Formal security arguments for 3 round feistal network using PRF

Tags: cbc, des, pseudo-random-function, pseudo-random-permutation, feistel-network

There is a proof sketch in Introduction to modern cryptography that a three-round feistel network using pseudorandom round functions is a secure pseudorandom permutation PRP Πk against probabilistic polynomial time adversaries which have access to Πk. Now my confusion is  to turn the proof sketch into a formal security arguments?